# Command for swap info in HPUX itanium and HPUX PARISC?

Tags: swap, hp-ux

I need to get commands for swap information in HPUX (both Itanium and PARISC).

Comment: If you're used to some other unix variant but unfamiliar with HP-UX, check out the [Unix rosetta stone](http://bhami.com/rosetta.html) or [UNIXguide.net](http://www.unixguide.net/unixguide.shtml) (both mention `swapinfo`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the `swapinfo` command for that.

if your systems have it installed, use the `kmeminfo` tool.  if they don't, you may still be able to get it from HP, but finding things on HP's site can be quite the chore, sometimes.